# How to make Bash's read abort after trapping interrupt?

Tags: bash, signals

Consider:

```
$ cat b.sh
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo $$ was interrupted' INT
read foo
echo done
$ ./b.sh
^C27104 was interrupted
^C27104 was interrupted
^C27104 was interrupted
done
$
```

(ctrl-c was hit 3 times, followed by ctrl-d)

I'd like the `read` to abort after execution of the trap.  Is there a clean way to make that happen?

Comment: I don't want to exit the script, just interrupt the read.

Comment: This could be useful [Unable to stop a bash script with Ctrl+C](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230421/unable-to-stop-a-bash-script-with-ctrlc/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like not interrupting immediately is a Bash non-POSIX extension (see `read_builtin` in `read.def` of Bash builtin source (look for `posixly_correct`)).

You can override this behavior, and exit on the first `Ctrl+C` by forcing POSIX behavior for `read` (by setting the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable):

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo $$ was interrupted' INT
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 read foo
echo done
```

Comment: Everyday learning something new - this is actually an prefect answer. +++ :)

Comment: @jm666, Thanks. I just found out this myself by peeking into the source. :)

Comment: @randomir: which version of bash did you use?

Comment: @Cyrus, Bash 4.3.